# Need to render a document data with mongoose referenced document data on react.js+redux

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, redux

It's a **MERN+Redux** project with **mongoose**.There are two schemas **"User"** and **"Reader"**.A particular **'user'** creates **'Readers'**.Need to render the each **'Reader'** along with the created 'user'.Backend is okay with the results when I checked by postman.**'Reader'** data can be rendered.But referenced user object can not be rendered on client page.Need a method to get extracted the referenced user object on client.

**reader.js(model-backend)**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const ReaderSchema = new Schema({
  readerId: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  availability: String,
  longitude: Number,
  latitude: Number,
  locationId: Number,
  date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "user" },
});

module.exports = Reader = mongoose.model("reader", ReaderSchema);
```

user.js(model-backend)

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  });
  
  module.exports = User = mongoose.model('user', UserSchema);
```

readers.js(routes-backend)

```
// @route   GET api/readers
// @desc    Get all readers 
// @access  Private
router.get('/', auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const readers = await Reader.find().sort({date:-1}).populate('user','-password');

    if (!readers) {
      return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'There are no readers' });
    }

    res.json(readers);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send('Server Error');
  }
});
```

RederItem.jsx (frontend-react)

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
const ReaderItem = ({
  reader: {
    readerId,
    availability,
    longitude,
    latitude,
    locationId,
    date,
    user,
    //name,
    // _id,
     //email
     user:{  _id, name, email, __v },
  },
  
 
}) => {
  return (
    <div className="profile bg-light">
      <div>
        <h2>
          ReaderID:<span>{readerId}</span>
        </h2>
        <p>
          Name:<span>{user.name}</span>
        </p>
         <p>
          Name:<span>{email}</span>
        </p> */}
         {user.map(u => <div>
          <p>{u.name}</p>
          <span>{u.email}</span>
          <p>{u._id}</p>
          </div>)} 
        <p>
          Availability:<span>{availability}</span>
        </p>
        <p>
          location:longitude<span>{longitude}</span>and Latitude
          <span>{latitude}</span>
        </p>
        <p>
          Location Code:<span>{locationId}</span>
        </p>
        <p>
          Time:<span>{date}</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ReaderItem;
```

**please refer these images**
[successfully GET each reader data along with the created user on postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsONA.jpg)

[Error when i render the referenced user object on client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1TaJ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

add `date` to user in ReaderItem like this

```
const ReaderItem = ({
  reader: {
    readerId,
    availability,
    longitude,
    latitude,
    locationId,
    date,
    user,
    //name,
    // _id,
     //email
     user:{  _id, name, date, email, __v },
  },
  
 
})
```

Comment: date is okay whether I put there or here I think.The issue is the referenced user object.Any property of user object can not get printed.Whenever I put just only  " user, " instead of " 
" user:{.........} " It renders only user id(_id) but I need to get rendered name and email of user.I can not get any property of user in user object to client side.But postman do it as I needed.

Comment: your backend send data correctly according to postman ,

Comment: yeah.backend is okay.The referenced document is the headache.I can not map it or extract.